Solution to Dirichlet problem with Dirac distribution boundary data
I am trying to find information for the following generic BVP with Dirac distribution as boundary condition,
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\nabla_x \cdot ({\bf\Gamma}  \cdot \nabla_x u(x,y))=0 & \text{in $\Omega$}\\ 
u(x,y)=\delta_y(x) & \text{on $\partial \Omega$}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
where $x,y\in \mathbb R^2 $, and $  {\bf\Gamma}  $ is a real $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix with positive, non-constant determinant. $\Omega$ is the exterior of the unit disk. The differential operator in the BVP looks like a Laplace-Beltrami operator, but for that to be the case the matrix ${\bf \Gamma}$ should have unit determinant, which is not the case.
This problem arises in the linearization of the potential equation for compressible flow ,
$$\nabla_x \cdot (\rho(x)\, \nabla_x \phi(x))=0.$$
In that context, ${\bf\Gamma} = \rho {\bf I} - \rho {\bf v} \otimes {\bf v} / c^2$ and  $\det({\bf\Gamma})=\rho^2(1-M^2)$, where ${\bf I} $ is the identity matrix, $\rho>0$ is the fluid's density, ${\bf v} = \nabla\phi$ the velocity vector, $c$ the speed of sound and $0\leq M < 1$ is the local Mach number. Likewise, given a normal vector ${\bf n}$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega $,
$$
{\bf n}\cdot{\bf \Gamma}\cdot \nabla_x u = \rho\, \partial_n u
$$
$u(x,y)$ can be thought of as a generalization of the Poisson kernel. In fact, the formal solution to the BVP would be
$$
u(x,x')=\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial  n_y}\rho(y)\delta_{x'}(y)\,dy = \frac{\partial G(x,x')}{\partial  n_{x'}}\rho(x') ,
$$
where $G(x,y)$ is the Green's function of the BVP. The issue at hand is of course how to find $G$ or $\partial G/ \partial n$ or at least establish some basic properties in terms of $\Gamma$. Any help or reference is greatly appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
